# Failed to export Firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying out the new export feature of the FireStore as shown on this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import), and I keep getting error message:

`gcloud alpha firestore export gs://backup --async`

`ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.firestore.export) PERMISSION_DENIED: Service account does not have access to Google Cloud Storage file: /backup. See https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#permissions for a list of permissions needed. Error details: projectABC@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to backup.`

I've run the command to add my service account as a storage.admin, and that command succeed:

`gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding projectABC --member='serviceAccount: projectABC@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' --role='roles/storage.admin'`

Could someone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't select an arbitrary bucket name for your backup.  You're using "gs://backup".  Instead, you need to use the url for an actual bucket that you've created an you fully control.

Comment: stupid me... I just need to put the full url, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. The Firebase docs don't make this clear they say to just put the name in.

Comment: I don't get it. There is no url for the firestore bucket. All the docs a reffering to just bucket name.

Answer (score -1):

Give storage admin access to IAM role